# How to get count number of customers based on date in Mongoose (MongoDB) in one query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm quite new to Mongoose (NoSQL) so I wonder how to calculate the number of users based on the date (`updated`).

Currently, I can get the total number of customers but I don't know how to get the number of users based on (today, this week or this month). In MySQL we can just put all the queries to get the information but I don't know how to do it in Mongoose in one query.

Here's the code

Customer Schema/Model

```
const customerSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  fullname: {
    type: String,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
  },
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  adminId: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

API

```
router.post("/getcustomer/:adminId", (req, res, next) => {
  const adminId = req.params.adminId;
  Customer.find({ adminId: adminId })
    .sort({ updated: "descending" })
    .exec()
    .then((docs) => {
      const response = {
        count: docs.length,
        customer_info: docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            fullname: doc.fullname,
            phone: doc.phone,
            address: doc.address,
            updated: doc.updated,
            adminId: doc.adminId,
            _id: doc._id,
          };
        }),
      };
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to group users based on updated field?

Comment: group by updated date and count by 1

Comment: [may be it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307611/mongodb-query-group-collection-by-date-last-week-month-all-nodejs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB query group collection by date last week/month/all NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307611/mongodb-query-group-collection-by-date-last-week-month-all-nodejs)

Comment: Since I'm using Mongoose, it's a lil bit confusing for me. Plus, the answer above doesn't return count and the information in 1 query. It looks like I have to make several APIs for the customer information count. How do I use the aggregate function in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the customers by date using aggregation:

```
Customers.aggregate([{$group: { _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$updated" }}, count:{$sum:1} }}])
```

Comment: I'm using Mongoose so how do I put that in my query?

Comment: You can use model.aggregate in mongoose. For example `Customer.aggregate([...])`

Comment: Please add explanation to avoid low quality answer